# Problems with cheap housings

Tags: shifter, cable, downtube-shifter, cable-housing

[image]

So, I converted my road bike from downtube shifters to STI brifters, and I noticed that the cable housings don't sit properly in the downtube cable stops, do you think that would be a problem ?

---

EDIT:

Yeah, I think that the housings are for brakes.

Comment: Looks like barrel adjuster is too big for the end cap, possibly for brake lines?

Comment: Something is missing in the adjusters or you've got the wrong type of adjusters.

Comment: I've never seen downtube mounts like that carrying brake cables, so it seems reasonable that the mounts are right-sized for gear cables which are definitely smaller than brake cables.   I'm quite stumped for coming up with a possible cause.   How old is the bike?

Comment: @Criggie the bike is like 2 months old

Comment: Weird- must have been a retro design because downtube shifters haven't been a thing for decades.   Please try the calipers and report back your measurements here, I'll go measure my downtube bosses in the morning.

Comment: @Criggie the adjuster's diameter is 7mm and the housing's is 5mm

Comment: For next time, it's almost always more cost-effective to buy the bike you actually want, rather than buy a bike that's not right for you and modify it.

Comment: It looks to me like you installed brake cables to operate the derailers.

Comment: The problem with the brake cable theory is that brake cables and their housings are thicker than derailleur cables.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will work fine for a while, but the slight angle will increase friction and therefore wear on that point of the cable.  This will make it harder to move too over time.

Water from rain or road spray will rust in there a little faster, and this can result in the housing popping out of the retainer easier.

I'd suggest using some calipers to measure the ID of your mounts, and the OD of your cable, and find a suitable end-cap/ferrule to fit.

Consider asking your LBS - Any good shop has drawers and boxes of little components like laying about.

Another bodge might be to find some thin-walled plastic tubing like garden irrigation pipe and fit a short piece over the chromed ferrule already installed.   I'd not recommend tape as a solution because it tends to mush, and helps hold water.